# How to change button control position?

Tags: html

I have to controls textbox and button.

```
<input type="text" size="25" style="height: 25px;" align-self="center" />
<input type="image" alt="Search" width="25px" height="25px" />
```

How can I change button position up or textbox down such that they look same line. I have tried with margin as well as padding, but it doesn't work.

See this image:
[image: my image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:middle` like this:

```
<input type="text" size="25" style="height: 25px; vertical-align:middle;" align-self="center"/>
<input type="image" alt="Search" width="25px" height="25px" style="vertical-align:middle;" />
```

[**DEMO (jsfiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/f4ybq/2/)